# Is it possible to pass in a variable (that contains XML element's ID) into (R.id.variableName)?

Tags: java, android

I want to iterate through a bunch of buttons which are in XML, so I gave each of them an id consisting of a letter and unique number (like q1,  q2,  q3, etc.).

Now in MainActivity I want to write a for loop that accesses each button by incrementing the id's number:

```
for (int i = 0; i <10; i++){
String buttonId = "q" + i;
findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
}
```

Java obviously doesn't allow this, so I'm hoping there are some neat alternatives to doing this.

Comment: ^ From the duplicate I've linked to above, in short, no

Comment: I know nothing about Android or, what `findViewById()` does, but often, when somebody asks about generating the name of a variable at run-time, the solution is to use a [`Map<String>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)